# OneDrive 2.0 Download File content 401 HTTP Code

Tags: c#, onedrive

I created an Azure AD application that has full access (R&W) to the OneDrive API using application permissions. (my application is a daemon app.) These permissions are granted & approved.

```
HTTP GET https://{MyTenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives//root://Document.docx
```

Returns 200 and content contains JSON information about the file

GET 2016-12-24T14:15:31.458 Requested uri:

```
https://{MyTenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives//root://Document.docx:/content

2016-12-24T14:15:31.888 StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { X-SharePointHealthScore: 0 SPRequestGuid: c935c49d-a0fa-3000-a357-32b18090ecd4 request-id: c935c49d-a0fa-3000-a357-32b18090ecd4 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN SPRequestDuration: 140 SPIisLatency: 1 MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.6008 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly Cache-Control: private Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2016 14:15:31 GMT P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI" Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 WWW-Authenticate: NTLM X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 16 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 } 2016-12-24T14:15:31.888 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

I added the Authorization header correctly. I created an Upload Function that sends the file to the same Document library and that works also correctly, same with the Delete functionality.

What is the reason of this 401, only when requesting the /content of the file? How could I troubleshoot this?

I loaded the JWT token into jwt.io : It has the following Roles : "roles": `[ "TermStore.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.Manage.All", "TermStore.Read.All", "Sites.Read.All", "Sites.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.FullControl.All" ]` What is going on here? The requested URI is : `https://<myTenantName>.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/<myDr‌​iveName>/root:/faas.‌​pptx:/content`

When using both types of GET request GET /drive/items/{item-id}/content `GET /drive/root:/{path and filename}:/content -> return 401 Unauthorized`

Best regards,

Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a long running issue with OneDrive for Business and "app-only" scenarios. You can keep track of the issue over at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/280.

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. 

When trying to download the file using SharePoint REST API, I retrieved the weburl first :
https://{myTenantName}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BB2CE1848-1FB6-4D7C-B0D9-B4DB8D08D910%7D&file=faas.pptx&action=default

Is it correct to perform a GET to the following resource : 

https://{myTenantName}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('faas.pptx')/$value

The file is located on a Document Library in the root folder of the tenant.

Comment: Never mind.  I found the correct syntax by exploring the SharePoint API.  Thanks @Brad for pointing me to the right direction !